# how to run multiple web servers on Tomcat in Eclipse(ubuntu)?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

It is showing port number clash. See the error below :
**Several ports (8080, 8080) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).**
How to change the port number of one of those?

Comment: I think all you need is this: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/ (not posting it as an answer because it's a link from another source).